# Error no deja añadir dependencias CardView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

estoy intentando implementar en mi proyecto un card view en mi layout, pero cuando lo pongo me marca como error,pero cuando añado las dependencias sigue marcando en rojo. He puesto las depencias en buidl.gradle tal como ponia la documentación oficial: `implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"`

Y lo que hago es esto:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Hotels"
    android:background="@color/blancoFondo">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>s
</LinearLayout>
```

El error que me salta: **Cannot resolve class android.support.v7.widget.CardView**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, tienes una **s** al final de tu línea:

```
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>s
```

Segundo, actualmente, el **`CardView`** se llama así:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: La s al final se me colo cuando estaba escribiendo la pregunta. Y como es que en la web de android te dan otra versión ?

Comment: Pues, porque ese manual no está actualizado. Aquí tienes el [enlace](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview) actualizado